# SQL Server : multiple rows single line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the representation of one record based on the primary key value from multiple tables. As shown below, each table can have multiple values based on this primary key value.

TABLE-1

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AA |
| 2 | BB |
| 3 | CC |
| 4 | DD |
| 5 | EE |

TABLE-2

| ID | SCHOOL | AUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | A |
| 2 | 11 | A |
| 2 | 12 | B |
| 3 | 11 | A |
| 4 | 12 | A |
| 4 | 13 | B |
| 5 | 13 | A |

TABLE-3

| ID | TC |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |
| 2 | 103 |
| 2 | 104 |
| 3 | 105 |
| 4 | 106 |
| 4 | 107 |
| 5 | 108 |

The result below is the value obtained with an `OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    T1.ID, T2.SCHOOL, T3.TC, T2.AUT 
FROM  
    T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
ORDER BY  
    T1.ID ASC
```

| ID | SCHOOL | TC | AUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 101 | A |
| 2 | 11 | 102 | A |
| 2 | 12 | 102 | B |
| 2 | 11 | 103 | A |
| 2 | 12 | 103 | B |
| 2 | 11 | 104 | A |
| 2 | 12 | 104 | B |
| 3 | 11 | 105 | A |
| 4 | 12 | 106 | A |
| 4 | 13 | 106 | B |
| 4 | 12 | 107 | A |
| 4 | 13 | 107 | B |
| 5 | 13 | 106 | A |

How can I get the result like below?

| ID | SCHOOL | TC1 | TC2 | TC3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 101 |  |  |
| 2 | 11 | 102 | 103 | 104 |
| 3 | 11 | 105 |  |  |
| 4 | 12 | 106 | 107 |  |
| 5 | 13 | 108 |  |  |

The important thing here is that in the result value, SCHOOL only shows that AUT is 'A'.

I would appreciate it if you let me know your query.

Comment: Did you try GROUP BY ID, SCHOOL?

Comment: There are cases where there are multiple SCHOOLs for each ID. At this time, I want to display only 'A' by referring to AUT of SCHOOL.

Comment: Do you mean WHERE AUT=A?

Comment: YES. And I want to show just one record per ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks, from your desired results, you just need to use `row_number` in combination with a conditional aggregate. Your sample data seems a little inadequate, I can't see any requirement for table1 at all.

Try the following:

```
with t as (
    select t2.id,t2.school,t3.tc, Row_Number() over(partition by t2.id order by t3.tc) col
    from t2 join t3 on t2.id=t3.id
    where aut='A'
)
select id,school,
    max(case when col=1 then tc end) TC1,
    max(case when col=2 then tc end) TC2,
    max(case when col=3 then tc end) TC3
from t
group by id, school
```

Example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e779f4/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID, T2.SCHOOL, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(T3.TC), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(T2.AUT) 
FROM 
    T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID 
GROUP BY 
    T1.ID, T2.SCHOOL 
WHERE 
    T2.AUT = ‘A’ 
ORDER BY 
    T1.ID ASC
```

Notice that [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) concatenates the values in the row.

**EDIT**: oh my, haven't seen that it's a SQL Server question!

Just replace `GROUP_CONCAT` with [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you’re using SQL Server 2017 or newer.

Comment: My SQL has group_concat
Can't use GROUP_CONCAT in MS SQL?
Is there any other way?

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer to reflect that you’re using MSSQL. If you’re using a version prior to 2017, then there are some uglier workarounds to STRING_AGG.

Comment: I am using is ms sql 2017 version.

Comment: So try it, and come back to tell us how it went :)

Comment: What you said helped me. However, if possible, it would be better if TC1, TC2, and TC3 could be expressed as separate fields instead of concatenating them with strings.

Comment: I do not think it is possible- for example, there might not always be 3, a priori.

Comment: you need to move the where clause to the join or you are getting rid of the left join to t2.